# Why is the format for referencing books sometimes backwards?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rambam, commentaries, writing-printing

The Rambam is usually reference in the following way: [פרק א׳ מהלכות ק״ש הלכה ט׳](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Reading_the_Shema.1.9)         - chapter 1 from from hilchos kerias shma, halacha 9.

Why is it referenced this way? Why not the way many other things are referenced, in order, which would be: [הלכות ק״ש פרק א׳ הלכה ט׳](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Reading_the_Shema.1.9) - hilchos kriyas shma, chapter 1, halacha 9.

This system has been in use for [centuries](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42048&st=&pgnum=3), and even in commentarys referencing Rambam use this system.

Additionally, I saw a quote elsewhere of באר היטב like this: ס׳ א׳ מאו׳ח ס״ק ו - reversed as well!

Comment: No, Gemmorah is also referenced this way, e.g. פרק קמא דקידושין.

Comment: Also you didn't mention by whom? Keep in mind that for centuries Rambam was the only book besides Gemmorah, arranged in books and chapters. So as I commented Rambam referencing follows Gemmorah's.